# ThreeJS: Mesh disappears if I change its posiion

Tags: three.js

```
        var orientation = {dim1: 100, dim2: 100, dim3: 100}
                geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(orientation.dim1, orientation.dim2, orientation.dim3);
                //geom.translate(orientation.dim1 / 2, orientation.dim2 / 2, orientation.dim3 / 2);
                box_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: 0xffffff,
                    transparent: false,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    alphaTest: 0.5
                });
                box_material.depthWrite  = true;

                var vertices = [];
                vertices.push( 0, 0, 0 );           
                geom.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 )) ;

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, box_material)

                //mesh.frustumCulled = false;

                scene.add(mesh);
```

This is the code that should create a box. If I don't set the attribute "position" it appear, but when I try to set its position it simply disappear. And if I try to move manually its position from the console it remains stuck.

What's the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the position of the box, simply use:

```
mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
```

Don't touch the `geom.setAttribute('position')` method because that would be destroying its vertices, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

make sure x,y, z are in number format, not string

or you can apply a transform

```
            pos.x = parseFloat((pos.x))
            pos.y = parseFloat((pos.y))
            pos.z = parseFloat((pos.z))
```